# How to make object move in exact gametime in Monogame, XNA?

Tags: 2d, graphics

I have recently started learning monogame. The big question i faced is how to make object move, when gametime variable has an exact value.

```
//Update method in Game.cs
     float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds / 1000f;
        if (CurrentState != null)
            CurrentState.update(delta);


     if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
            SetState(new GameState());

    //GameState.cs, there is a box that's need to be moved in 5 seconds
    Vector2 boxpos = new Vector2(800, Game1.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2 - 100);
    float olddelta = 0;
    public void update(float delta)
    {
        float newdelta = delta;
        if (newdelta - olddelta >= 5)
        {
            boxpos += new Vector2(0, -200);
            olddelta = newdelta;
        }
    }
```

I've drawn a box in my gamestate's draw method using `spritebatch.Draw(Box, boxpos, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);`, but it's position remains constant. 
I really have no idea how to do it in a right way. Hope can receive some help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to step through your program, I suspect that your clause of >= 5 is never being met here. As you are taking in a frame in milliseconds, and taking away the previous frame, this value will remain very low. What you should be using here is an accumulation of time, so to reach that five second mark.

For a good reference on the subject, have a read of the following http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ It goes through the steps on implementing a time step correctly, and the reasoning behind it in a clear manner

Comment: His olddelta stays the same until the difference reaches 5

Comment: @Bálint Yes, but he is comparing the delta between two timesteps, which wouldn't differ by 5 msecs, unless the machine stalls noticeably. newdelta should be incremented by delta instead of being assigned directly.

Answer (score 0):

In your gamestate code, `olddelta` value is only assigned in two places.

First it is assigned to `0` in the beginning.

Then, it is assigned to the value of `newdelta` (which is effectively a copy of `delta` - the extra variable is not really necessary), but only on the condition of `delta` being more than or equal to 5 (seconds?), at which point it will get assigned to that value. Next time around the check would be for a value that's more than 5+ whatever value passed the check last time, so something over 10.

All in all highly unlikely to happen and definitely not the intention of the code.

What you likely intended to do is to add the value of `delta` to `olddelta` or some better named variable and then check the value of that second variable. When it exceeds 5, you perform your action.

Side note, if you want to perform your action *every* 5 seconds, once the action is performed, you subtract 5 from your accumulating variable.

The way the title is worded, there seems to be a second question that asks if it is possible to do this exactly, the answer for this is - not with this method, you will probably be a frame (so around 17ms) late most of the time.